# Uniformizer of an elliptic curve at infinity

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have read in a solution to a problem that I was studying that $t = \frac{x}{y}$ is a uniformizer at the point $(0,1,0)$ of the curve given by $y^2z=x^3+axz^2+bz^3$, and that one can expand $x=t^{-2}+...$ and $y=t^{-3}+...$. I am not sure how one gets this and was hoping someone could clarify?

Comment: The uniformizer is actually $x/y$, not $y/x$, and its derivation is given in my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3335091/

Comment: @djao thanks, that was very helpful. Do you have any idea of a recipe to write down an expansion of a function on the elliptic curve in terms of the uniformizer around $(0,1,0)$.

Comment: Equations (2) and (4) of https://aghitza.github.io/pdf/other/velu.pdf give you $x$ and $y$ in terms of the uniformizer. For any other rational function, do power series arithmetic on these series. For example if you want $x^2+y$ then take the power series of $x$, square it, and add the power series of $y$.